# Condição CSS com jQuery, ex: se div1 estiver visivel a div2 também estará

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fala galera não manjo muito Js/jQuery, mas preciso do seguinte que uma `<div>` oculte quando uma outra `<div>` estiver oculta também.

Ex: Quando o botão comprar estiver oculto uma `<div>` com os descontos ocultar também e exibir uma `<div>` indisponível.

Estava seguindo alguns exemplos existentes e fiz isso:

```
unavailableProductDefault: function(){
    if ($('.buyButtonWrapper').length){ //botão comprar
        $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper') .hide(); //div flags descontos
        $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper2') .show(); // div flag Indisponivel
        $('.ui-accordion') .hide(); // oculta o accordion de parcelamento
    }
    else {
        $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper') .show();
        $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper2') .hide();
        $('.ui-accordion') .show();
    }
},
```

**[Arquivo completo do JS](http://www.rs1.com.br/arquivos/rs1.functions.base-notifyme.js)**

Comment: Dá algum erro no seu código? Resultado esperado, resultado obtido? Acho que fica mais fácil se você montar um StackSnippet ou JSFiddle que demonstre o problema isoladamente (html e js básico).

Comment: Não da nenhum erro, mas não exibe o resultado esperado. Não sei se da pra eu postar o código pois estou usando na plataforma e-commerce.

Comment: Não vejo `unavailableProductDefault` no seu código .js. Onde está ele?

Comment: Então Sergio, o código estou usando local a plataforma tem um sistema que posso fazer Proxy reverso e usar os arquivos locais e com LiveReload.

Answer (score 3):

Já que está usando jQuery você pode usar o `toggle()`

```js
$("#esconde").on('click', function(){
        $("#botao,#parcelamento").toggle('slow')
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="botao">
    <input type="submit"/>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="esconde" value='Esconder botao e parcelamento'/>
<div id="parcelamento">
    <ul>
        <li>parcelamento 1</li>
        <li>parcelamento 2</li>
        <li>parcelamento 3</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Agora você só tem que adaptar pro seu sistema.

Comment: Oi, periotto, o legal é colocar aqui uma mostra do código e linkar pro fiddle como demonstração. Dependendo do caso, e este pode ser um, fica mais legal usando um [StackSnippet](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2115/apresentando-js-css-e-html-execut%c3%a1veis?cb=1)

Comment: brasofilo obrigado pela dica, já vou alterar :D

Comment: Cara obrigado pela ajuda, mas acho que não expliquei direito.

Quero fazer o seguinte: se a `div1` estiver visivel a `div2` também será exibida, caso a `div1` não esteja visivel a `div2` também não estará.

Answer (score 2):

No teu código não estás a verificar se o elemento está visível ou não, estás a verificar se ele existe na página.

Pelo que entendo da tua lógica, o elemento existe sempre na página, quer esteja visível quer não:

```
if ($('.buyButtonWrapper').length) { ... }
```

Nunca entra no `else` porque o elemento está presente no DOM, só não está é visível para o utilizador.

## Solução

Para verificar se o elemento está visível, em jQuery podes fazer uso do método [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que vai verificar o elemento "contra" um seletor, neste caso o [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```js
// Se "Comprar" está visivel
if ($('.buyButtonWrapper').is(':visible')) {

  $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper').hide();   // div flags descontos
  $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper2').show();  // div flag Indisponivel
  $('.ui-accordion').hide();                         // accordion de parcelamento
}

// Se "Comprar" está escondido
else {
  $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper').show();
  $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper2').hide();
  $('.ui-accordion').show();
}
```

O teu código pode ainda ser otimizado para:

```js
// colocar elementos em cache
var $descontos    = $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper'),  // div flags descontos
    $indisponivel = $('.bloco-flags-desconto .flagsWrapper2'), // div flag Indisponivel
    $parcelamento = $('.ui-accordion');                        // accordion de parcelamento

if ($('.buyButtonWrapper').is(':visible')) {
  // Se "Comprar" está visivel
  $descontos.hide();
  $indisponivel.show();
  $parcelamento.hide();
}
else {
  // Se "Comprar" está escondido
  $descontos.show();
  $indisponivel.hide();
  $parcelamento.show();
}
```

A segunda versão do código é preferível porque se tiveres que atualizar os seletores, só precisas mexer nos valores das variáveis, não precisas andar a fazer múltiplas atualizações mais para baixo no meio do código.